# Is there any way to autopopulate form fields based on a JSON file that will be uploaded via a Load button in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend

I am trying to make an application that would have a form that gets autofilled once the user uploads a JSON file and clicks the load button , so I was wondering if there's any way to achieve this .

Thanks

Comment: Consider using formik. Then upon submission of the json file, Object.keys(formik.values).forEach(key=>formik.setFieldValue(key, jsonData[key])) .

In plain English. For each key in the formik values, set the value to the corresponding key's data in the jsonData

Answer (score 1):

That's totally possible. Just make the file upload write a JSON to state (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/) and then when the user clicks a button, scan through the uploaded JSON for the relevant keys. When you find a key, just use the value associated with it and set the state value of the associated form element.